# Magento 2 - Missing enable / disable cache options

Tags: magento2, cache

In my Magento 2, I can't **enable/disable** cache In System -> Cache Management, the two options are missing from the dropdown menu. what went wrong?

It's in *Production mode*.

[image]

I can only enable / disable cache via CLI.

Comment: Magento Does not allow you to enable or disable cache types in Admin when production mode is enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it is meant to be like this in Magento **2.2** when **production mode** enabled

> **production mode**
>
> Intended for deployment on a production system, this mode:
>
> Does not show exceptions to the user (exceptions are written to logs
>    only).
>
> Serves static view files from cache only. Prevents automatic
>    code file compilation.
>
> New or updated files are not written to the
>    file system.
>
> **Does not allow you to enable or disable cache types in
>    Magento Admin**.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html#mode-production

Answer (score 1):

Magento is happy for you to enable/disable the cache using the commandline while in production mode:

```
[user@host ~/public_html]$  php bin/magento cache:enable
```

or

```
[user@host ~/public_html]$  php bin/magento cache:disable
```

IMO its silly not to be able to switch the cache on/off in Magento admin while running in production mode.  Its handy for troubleshooting and switching from production to developer mode is way overkill to simply enable/ disable cache as it causes downtime during the switch and drastically reduced performance.  It would be a much better idea to simply warn magento users if any part of the cache is disabled with a notification than to completely remove all actions from the cache management screen.

Just my two satoshis.

Answer (score -2):

```
I have fixed by disabling Production Mode by going

app/etc/env.php
```

Replace this with

```
'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
'MAGE_MODE' => 'production',
'session' => [
    'save' => 'files'
],
```

with

```
  'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'MAGE_MODE' => 'default',
    'session' => [
        'save' => 'files'
    ],
```